# Calculate Duration of "In Progress" List Items from Start Date To End Date (Moved To Complete)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

This method will also need to take into account Weekends and only record the workdays that the List item has been In Progress.

So Far I have a calculated Column that establishes The amount of time since the Status Was Changed from New --> In Progress

```
=IF(Status="IN PROGRESS",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a formula that will give an up to date value (using NOW()) when the items are displayed in a list, then it can't be done with a Calculated Column. Calculated Columns are only updated with an item is added or updated.

The following formula calculates the number of working days (M-F) between two weekday dates. There are two assumptions: The date values are Dates and not Date and Time, and the date values are Monday to Friday only.

```
=[Due Date] - [Start Date] + 1 -
  IF( [Due Date] < ( [Start Date] + ( 5 - WEEKDAY([Start Date],3) ) ),
    0,
    FLOOR(  ( ([Due Date]-([Start Date]+(5-WEEKDAY([Start Date],3))))  /7),1)*2 + 2
  )
```

The first line is all that is needed if both dates are in the same week.

The rest of the formula tests to see if the both dates are in the same week, and if so, makes no adjustment (0), otherwise deducts two days for each weekend between the two dates.

This formula does not allow for when start or end date is a weekend date. You could add extra logic to test for this. Add validation to the two date columns to require M-F dates and that the start date must be before the end date!

Comment: Looking for a method that does not have a literal end date, just essentially to track In Progress tickets to see how much time has elapsed since the Status Column for a List item has been Moved to In Progress.
The return value I have already, I just need to tell that function to only add days between Mon-Fri